# keras ImageDataGenerator without data augmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, tf.keras

My question is how to make a image generator in keras without any augmentation. I would like to create training and validation generator, in order to pass this to model.fit_generator, because the size of dataset is larger than my RAM memory on my laptop.

Would it be possible if I don't pass any argument to `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()`?

Comment: Pretty sure the default ImageDataGenerator doesn't perform any augmentation unless you specify it

Comment: @Mike Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: If you found the comment helpful, I've posted it as an answer so you can mark the problem as solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default ImageDataGenerator doesn't perform any augmentation unless you specify it within its arguments.